# Опасно ли что пользователи могут получить раздел wp-admin?

Tags: wordpress

возник такой вопрос
На большинства сайтов WP можно получить доступ к форме авторизации админа, введя site.ru/wp-admin
Открывает ли это какие то дыры в системе безопасности? Если да то каким образом можно устранить?

Comment: Никаких дыр в WordPress нет. И указанная форма не создает никаких проблем.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо большое

Comment: )
Можете попробовать просканировать свой сайт на уязвимости, надеюсь это поможет обезопасить ваш ресурс)
https://codeby.net/threads/skaner-ujazvimostej-ot-codeby.67374/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Открывает ли это какие то дыры в системе безопасности? Если да то
>   каким образом можно устранить?

*Вопрос вообще дискуссионный и имеет много разных мнений. Вплоть до противоположных. Но думаю будет интересен многим.*

Разработчики уверяют, что всё безопасно. Однако уже были случаи повышение привилегий юзеров. Хотя и было это давно, но кто даст гарантии что это не возникнет вновь? Тем более что регулярно обнаруживающиеся уязвимости как раз и могут использоваться юзерами, с доступом к `/wp-admin/`.  А ещё эта гутенбергинизация ВП...

Я лично не рекомендую пускать никого постороннего в админку. Это, кроме потенциальной опасности, просто не серьёзно выглядит. Всё, что может делать юзер, он должен делать с фронта. И что бы не мог напрямую получить доступ к скриптам в `/wp-admin/` *(частично это не возможно, тк как минимум логиниться он должен, но в остальном надо ограничивать и проверять).*

Дополнительной мерой безопасности является заведение таких пользователей в отдельной таблице с делегацией им нужных возможностей. Так делают некоторые плагины для многопользовательских систем.

И вообще есть такое негласное правило: админка - она для админов. Для пользователей - "личный кабинет".

Ида. Если не ошибаюсь в далёких планах разработчиков ВП есть и построение нормальной многопользовательской архитектуры. Возможно тогда ситуация измениться к лучшему.